# Is AsyncTask suitable for drawing a Bitmap on canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-asynctask

I've seen some code on this site that does that but I don't understand how it can work. From what I understand, AsyncTask is only suitable for tasks of only a few seconds and only executed once. For drawing bitmap on a canvas, it has to be redrawn over and over to be displayed on the canvas so  I don't see how AsyncTask can work.

Will it be advisable to draw Bitmap on canvas using AsyncTask?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are right, Async tasks are best used for something that is only executed once. As a result, You could possibly use an AsyncTask to decode the bitmap and store it in a variable.
This variable can then by used to render the bitmap in the onDraw()

A SurfaceView might also be more useful for what you need.